# Required wordpress theme files to make it installable for others

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a theme on wordpress on local with xampp and wordpress.org but now i dont know which files should i .zip so others can use my theme. I tried with those files below to test if the theme works but its not working when i upload it as a theme in wordpress:
[image]

Which files should i include in the .zip archive so the theme will be installable and have everything on it such as pages posts etc...

Comment: That's not how Wordpress works. A them id not a recreation of the website, it defines hoe it looks and some functionality. Pages, posts, plugins etc are not part of the theme. Pages & posts are part of your website stored in the the WP database. Plugins are separate add-ons that are installed independently.

Comment: so for example if i want to submit it on wordpress.org or on envato theme forest, what are the necessary files?

Comment: @Xhynk has already given you this information in their answer below. If you need more information then that, I suggest you look up the documentation or do some tutorials about how to create a WP theme, as that will explain what a theme should include and how to include it.

Answer (score 2):

You only need the `/wp-content/themes/YOUR-THEME` folder. Everything else should already be there on other people's WordPress installations, as they are core files. Also never ever ever ever **ever** include your `wp-config.php` file with anybody. That contains sensitive database credentials that, if compromised, can give anybody access to **everything** on your site.

Comment: when i archive the theme folder and it installs sucessfuly but the plugins i used and the style is not on the new website, only the posts and pages are there, images, style and plugins are not